# Node.js Meteor create a splash page with password to enter into the app. Keeping user login separate and inside the app past the splash page

Tags: node.js, meteor

Wanting to create a splash page where a user can enter a site password that is the same for everyone.  It's to hide the site while it's in preview only.  Not sure why I'm not getting how to do this.  It's got to be relatively straight forward in meteor.

Currently have Meteor-Router installed.  Is this the best approach?  How do I go about this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need the notion of a user account after they get past the splash page?

Comment: Currently the app is using accounts a little bit.  Once past the splash page, then a user would login with their actual username/password.  The splash page is just to block people from seeing anything in the app before the app is released to the public.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible answer in CoffeeScript:

Add a filter on the `Router` like:

```
Meteor.Router.filters
  'authorizeUser': (page) ->
    if Session.get 'knowsTheSecret' then page else 'splash'

Meteor.Router.filter 'authorizeUser'
```

That says every page request must have the `knowsTheSecret` session variable set or the user will get booted back to the `splash` page (defined elsewhere).

On the server (as in put this in the `server` directory). Create a method to validate the password:

```
Meteor.methods
  checkSecret: (string) ->
    string is 'super secret password'
```

When the user clicks the login button on your splash page, you can call the method like so:

```
Template.splash.events
  'click button': ->
    password = $('#text-field').val()
    Meteor.call 'checkSecret', password, (err, result) ->
      Session.set 'knowsTheSecret', result
```

So the `Session` varable will only get set if the user actually knows the secret. This, of course, is not secure in any real way (They user could just open a console and set the session variable manually) but it's a start. Play around with all that and see if it gets you closer to a working solution.

Comment: Where does that code go.


I have this:
`console.log('Found filters');
Meteor.Router.filters({
    'checkSplashPage': function(page){
        console.log('filtering');
        if (Session.get('knowsTheSecret')){
            return page;
        }else{
            return 'splash';
        }
    }
});

Meteor.Router.filter('checkSplashPage');
`


In the console of the browser it outputs: "Found filters"
But it never triggers the checkSplashPage function

Not sure how to get this to work?

Seems like there should be some way to do this from the server side code instead?

What would you suggest?

Comment: I just had the chance to try all this out and it worked but I realized I forgot to send the password in the method call. I updated the answer with an example which assumes you have a button and a text field on a template called `splash`. As for where the code goes - it doesn't really matter since it's meteor. You could put all of that in a single file under the `client` directory if you want (except for the definition of `checkSecret`).